# Why is PDO returning Result when it shouldn't?

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo, resultset

I have just one text field where a user can enter there username or email address to reset there password.

First here is the code: (I only included code that I know where problem resides).

```
try {

    // connect to database
    $dbh = sql_con();

    // prepare query
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("
                     SELECT COUNT(*)
                     FROM
                         users
                     WHERE
                         user_login = :username
                     OR
                         user_email = :email
                     ");

    // execute query
    $stmt->execute(array(':username' => $username_email, ':email' => $username_email));

    if ($stmt->fetchAll() > 0) {

        // something was found
        // just echoing at the moment until i figure out what i am doing wrong
        echo 'i found something';
        exit;

    } else {
        // nothing found
        echo 'i found nothing';
        exit;
    }

}
catch (PDOException $e) {

    ExceptionErrorHandler($e);
    require_once($footer_inc);
    exit;
}
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong, probably something very silly, but when I enter a username or email address that I know is not in the database it still `echo`es out **I found something**.

What I am doing wrong?

I was going to use `rowCount` but as suggested by the PHP manual it states:

> `PDOStatement::rowCount()` returns the number of rows affected by the last `DELETE`, `INSERT`, or `UPDATE` statement executed by the corresponding PDOStatement object.
>   If the last SQL statement executed by the associated `PDOStatement` was a `SELECT`.
>   statement, some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement.
>   However, this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications.

So basically the PHP manual is saying I should do a `Count(*)` before performing my real query then work with the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you maybe mean `if (count($stmt->fetchAll()) > 0) {`

Comment: thank you... i altered code to what you shown above and altered SQL query and it now works. Thank you, phplover

Answer (score 3):

That's because `fetchAll()` returns an array. even if the query result has no rows, you still get at least an empty array, and...

```
php > var_dump(array() > 0);
bool(true)
```

You need to do

```
if ($stmt->rowCount > 0) { ... }
```

instead. And besides, you're doing a `COUNT(*)`, so regardless of what's matched, you'll get a single row result that contains the matched count. You'd need to fetch that one row, and check the value of that counted field.

Comment: It is mentioned in the question why he does not use this. That's why I'm voting down.

Answer (score 0):

$statement -> fetchAll () will return an array.  Comparing it to 0 makes no sense.  You probably meant to count() the number of elements in the resultset returned from $statement -> fetchAll ()